# Scheduled APEX job configured to run monthly but running daily?

Tags: apex, scheduled, jobs

I inherited an org that has some APEX scheduled jobs.  The configuration pages shows the job to run on the 1st day of each month:
[image: Manage scheduled job]

In the Scheduled Jobs view, this job appears like it is running daily:
[image]

Is anyone aware of a feature/bug that would cause this mismatch?  Is this kind of glitch something to be expected on the platform?  I assume the fix is to delete and reschedule the job.

Any assistance appreciated.

---

Follow up screenshot to David's spot on answer:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a UI bug/quirk. The user interface scheduler cannot display all possible schedules, but it doesn't make that clear and instead shows an incorrect monthly schedule.

The Next Scheduled Run column is correct, and you can get the actual schedule details by querying the `CronTrigger` object:

```
SELECT CronJobDetail.Name, CronExpression FROM CronTrigger
```